# Custom Component injected into table row

Tags: html, angular

I have a table that is created in one componentA that has several table-row elements in the table. I then have another componentB that just has several table-row elements that will be reused throughout the app in the template code. The issue is that when using componentB inside of the table of componentA the table-row elements are not spanning the entire width of the table and seem to be broken outside of the table.

I have found references to several other similar issues, but they are using dynamic rows based on data that is passed in for each row. My issue is that I have a fixed set of rows that will be used throughout the app. I tried using the following examples:

```
--- componentA
<table>
 <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
 <tr componentB></tr> --- does not work
</table>

--- componentB --- selector: '[componentB]'
<tr><td>Phone Number</td></tr>
<tr><td>Email</td></tr>

--- componentA
<table>
 <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
 <componentB></componentB> --- does not work
</table>

--- componentB --- selector: 'componentB'
<tr><td>Phone Number</td></tr>
<tr><td>Email</td></tr>
```

Here is an example stackblitz of exactly the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydsgaz

The  elements in componentB should span the width of the table just like a normal  element used in componentA, but they are not. Any help would be great!

ANSWER: either one of the following examples will work for this scenario

- content-projection: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dr6fqs
- template reference (my preferred way): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgxzhv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use angular content projection.
You just have to add a directive selector to table body.
**app.component.html**

```
<table>
  <tbody app-table-rows>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>bob</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

and then in **table-rows.component.html** add `ng-content` element. Angular will replace this `ng-content` element with content inside directive host element.

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<tr>
  <td>email</td>
  <td>bob@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
...
```

Working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dr6fqs

Comment: Great idea and works really well! However, my real world situation is actually a little more trickier than that. But you have me a great idea. Here is my final result: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgxzhv